# magento change session name to PHPSESSID

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

> We have a legacy application (raw PHP) that is loaded from an Iframe
>   in the Magento Frontend View. Now we need to detect from that legacy
>   application if the user is logged in or not.
>
> We had tried to store a value to $_SESSION from the Magento but while
>   trying it, we realized that Magento uses different session name.
>
> Do you have any alternative on how we can detect if the user is logged
>   in or not from the legacy application that is loaded in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if user is logged in in the application with this piece of code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
After you can get information about user. For example:

$customer=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
echo "<pre>" print_r($customer);
```

and for example set `$_SESSION['username']=$customer->getName();`

Comment: As I said, Magento uses different session name (i.e frontend) and might have different session settings (i.e session_path).

Comment: ah ok so use : 
Don't use $_SESSSiON var.
Add something to the session like this:

 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('key_here', 'value_here');

To read it from the session do this:

 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('key_here');

or if you want to retrieve the value and remove it from the session do this:

 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('key_here', true);